# How to update datas without reloading a page after deleting a doc on firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a button that use this function to delete a value from firebase, these values are shown in a flatlist in the same page, the function works good but to see the changes I need to reload the page or go back and return on it.

This is my function

```
   const onDelete = (sizeId) => {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("Measures")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection(route.params.size)
            .doc(sizeId)
            .delete()
```

How can I make it refresh after the changes so I can see the new flatlist without the value that I deleted?

Comment: Can you show us how you read the data? Do you read it once or use a realtime listener?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a React.Class you can try using a PureComponent. Upon removing the value from the state array, you could use a boolean state that you flip between true and false to trigger a re-render. 
If you are using a functional component and you keep the data in a useState hook, you can cause a re-render via useEffect on that state upon change.

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

useEffect( () => {}, [arr] ); //This listens for state changes on arr and will cause a re-render upon change.
```

This would only work if you aren't setting state in your useEffect as it will cause an infinite loop if you call setArr() in your useEffect. In which case I have used a simple boolean that I flip back and forth when I want a re-render.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using a FlatList to show the items